# Access volume control button Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to access Volume Control Button in WP8 programmatically. I know in WP7 it was not possible. But in WP8 it is possible to do so. Please have a look at ["Kirik Settings"](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/kirik-settings/673dd6e6-29ac-463c-81d0-89b04a381a3c) which can access the volume control buttons. Can I know how to implement the same ?

Comment: @AMR: Hi, I am searching for an API or a class to access the same.

Comment: @Liam: Hi my question is for Windows Phone 8 not for Windows 8. So I think my question is legit and not a duplicate. Can you please remove the question ? It is hurting my points.

Comment: This is hardly a duplicate of the mentioned question, probably should be reopened.

Comment: voting to reopen, not a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app you link does not access the volume buttons, it just disguisses itself as an background audio agent. If you want to create a similar app, background audio agent is the way to go, more info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039(v=vs.105).aspx